# Linking images to the right page

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

Im building my own CMS. Users can create posts and are also able to upload a picture with the current post. So when a user creates a post and uploads a picture, the image url is inserted into the database into a table where I store all the image urls. My problem is that I have no idea how to relate the uploaded image to the current post while inserting the data of the post into the database.

So my database exists of a post table which holds the following row names: id, subject, intro, post, and a image_id. (image_id for joining the right image.id when I have the value)
My images table exist just out of an id and an image_url.

So when a user posts a message and uploads an image with it, how can I insert the data in the database so the image is linked to the post?

Thanks!

Comment: you need post id with each images. when you are upload an image you need to pass post id with it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how to get the post id of something that hasn't been posted yet.

Comment: To have many photos by post try to use this structure :
images(idIMG,idPOST,urlIMG,.....) where the PK for images is (idIMG+idPOST)

Comment: when someone uploaded image then just save the image in your image directory and set a hidden input field in your form for image url. set image url in image url hidden field. when you submit the form then you will have a post data with image url. then save post data in post table and image url and post id in your images table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first insert the image information:

```
$image_query = "INSERT INTO images SET image_url = :image_url";
$image_result = $pdo->prepare( $image_query );
$image_result->execute( array(
    ":image_url" => $image_url
));
```

Then get the image_id from the insert:

```
$image_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Then insert the post:

```
$post_query = "INSERT INTO posts SET subject = :subject, intro = :intro, post = :post, image_id = :image_id";
$post_result = $pdo->prepare( $post_query );
$post_result->execute( array(
    ":subject"  => $subject,
    ":intro"    => $intro,
    ":post"     => $post,
    ":image_id" => $image_id
));
```

You'll have to modify the variable names above depending on your situation, and this assumes that you're using PDO where $pdo is the connection to your MySQL database.  But this is essentially the process you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your database post table. There should not be image id in post table.
you should have post id in your images table.

images belongs to post. post not belongs to images.

```
Images

 -- image_id
 -- image_path
 -- post_id
```

when someone uploaded image then just save the image in your image directory and set a hidden input field in your form for image url. set image url in image url hidden field. when you submit the form then you will have a post data with image url. then save post data in post table and image url and post id in your images table.

I know it is descriptive answer and i have tried to describe it.

It should make sense!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can handle that in two different ways:

One is put the image field on the post table, if you need the image in a separated field.
So that way you will have in your post field some like:

`names: id, subject, intro, post, and a image_path`

The second way is... and I think that is the most popular into the CSMs, if you don't need the image in a separate field, may you can put all together saving it as html.

This two possibilities that I suggest you is considering that it is not necessary must to put the images in another table. If you have a necessity of that, may this is not what you are look for.